# google script financeapp refresh

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a script that will check some values in a google spreadsheet and email me the results.  The values it is checking are mostly from the FinanceApp (various stock prices for the past month), and everything works beautifully when the spreadsheet is open, but when the spreadsheet is closed (I have a time trigger set to run the script daily) I receive emails containing NaN instead of actual values!

Here is the skeleton of my code:

```
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var rows = sheet.getRange(range);
    var values = rows.getValues();
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, "stock stuff", values);
```

Here is an example of the kinds of values I'm retrieving from the FinanceApp:

```
    =GoogleFinance("GOOG","PRICE")
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

---

I ended up moving all the finance stuff into the script which runs daily after the stock market is closed. The script emails me the information as a sort of daily digest and also stores it in the spreadsheet so I can look at it anytime.

This way the spreadsheet has no logic and is only a view.  While this is not a solution to my original question, my original approach was flawed because of this mixing of views and logic :)

Comment: Probably this  error is coming due to the array you are passing in mail body. Try MailApp.sendEmail(email, "stock stuff", Utilities.jsonStringify(values));

Comment: I ended up moving all the finance stuff into the script which runs daily after the stock market is close. and using the spreadsheet only to display the results